# Как вывести категорию кастомных записей

Tags: php, wordpress

Я создал кастомный тип записей "Портфолио". На странице в класс контейнера данных записей мне нужно добавить их категорию. Как я могу это реализовать?

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );

function register_post_types(){

        $labels = array(
            'name'               => esc_html__( 'Portfolio', 'askam' ),
            'singular_name'      => esc_html__( 'Portfolio', 'askam' ),
            'menu_name'          => esc_html__( 'Portfolio', 'askam' ),
            'parent_item_colon'  => esc_html__( 'Parent Item:', 'askam' ),
            'all_items'          => esc_html__( 'All Items', 'askam' ),
            'view_item'          => esc_html__( 'View Item', 'askam' ),
            'add_new_item'       => esc_html__( 'Add New Item', 'askam' ),
            'add_new'            => esc_html__( 'Add New', 'askam' ),
            'edit_item'          => esc_html__( 'Edit Item', 'askam' ),
            'update_item'        => esc_html__( 'Update Item', 'askam' ),
            'search_items'       => esc_html__( 'Search Item', 'askam' ),
            'not_found'          => esc_html__( 'Not found', 'askam' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => esc_html__( 'Not found in Trash', 'askam' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'label'               => esc_html__( 'portfolio', 'woodmart' ),
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'page-attributes' ),
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 28,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => $has_archive,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'rewrite'             => array(
                'slug'       => $portfolio_slug,
                'with_front' => false,
                'feeds'      => true,
            ),
            'capability_type'     => 'page',
            'show_in_rest'        => true,
        );

        register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );

    
    
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => esc_html__( 'Portfolio Categories', 'askam' ),
            'singular_name'         => esc_html__( 'Portfolio Category', 'askam' ),
            'search_items'          => esc_html__( 'Search Categories', 'askam' ),
            'popular_items'         => esc_html__( 'Popular Project Categories', 'askam' ),
            'all_items'             => esc_html__( 'All Project Categories', 'askam' ),
            'parent_item'           => esc_html__( 'Parent Category', 'askam' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => esc_html__( 'Parent Category', 'askam' ),
            'edit_item'             => esc_html__( 'Edit Category', 'askam' ),
            'update_item'           => esc_html__( 'Update Category', 'askam' ),
            'add_new_item'          => esc_html__( 'Add New Category', 'askam' ),
            'new_item_name'         => esc_html__( 'New Category', 'askam' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'   => esc_html__( 'Add or remove Categories', 'askam' ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => esc_html__( 'Choose from most used text-domain', 'askam' ),
            'menu_name'             => esc_html__( 'Category', 'askam' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'public'            => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => false,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'show_tagcloud'     => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                'slug'         => $portfolio_category_slug,
                'with_front'   => false,
                'hierarchical' => true,
            ),
            'capabilities'      => array(),
            'show_in_rest'      => true,
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_category', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );


}
```

Мне нужно как то добавить в контейнер article добавить ее категорию. У меня созданы отдельные файлы archive-portfolio, single-portfolio и тп.

Comment: Переменная $has_archive не определена, значит, null. Приводится к false и как результат, архивов нет.

Comment: а как это исправить,  я немного кофеварка

Comment: 'has_archive'         => true,

Comment: но как вывести категорию произвольного типа записи? Никак не могу найти нужный код в интернете